# Win 7 ethernet not connecting to internet

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7, ASUS Desktop computer will not connect to internet with motherboard ethernet port, but will with USB wifi adapter, which makes internet slower.

I have done everything I know including:
Flushing DNS list
Flushing IP table
Giving it manual IP address and DNS
Giving it automatic IP address and DNS
Disable IPv6 connection
Completely removed and reinstalled up-to-date drivers
Giving it a fixed IP from the router
Disabling Avast antivirus, Avast firewall and Windows firewall
netsh interface ipv4 reset and ipv6 reset

Windows 7, ASUS Desktop computer will not connect to internet with motherboard ethernet port, but will with USB wifi adapter, which makes internet slower.

I have done everything I know including:
Flushing DNS list
Flushing IP table
Giving it manual IP address and DNS
Giving it automatic IP address and DNS
Disable IPv6 connection
Completely removed and reinstalled up-to-date drivers
Giving it a fixed IP from the router
Disabling Avast antivirus, Avast firewall and Windows firewall
netsh interface ipv4 reset and ipv6 reset

Router (ATT U-vers), sees the connection but does not get packets. Other devices using ethernet and wifi work fine.

When I set up the adapter connection it gives me a Broadband selection but only PPPoe or dialup. And lists it as a Public network, Local Area Connection.

Any Ideas?

Comment: With ethernet connected run the windows internet troubleshooter, right click on the icon in the systray and choose "troubleshoot problems" What does it report?

Comment: First things first, try using a new ethernet cord.